# Solving ODEs, Rotations, Angular Velocity, Euler Angles

Tags: scipy, integration

I am implementing a simulation that needs to rotate and object based
on known angular velocity (assumed constant for simplicity). I followed the
ideas given below, pg. 32)

https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs448b-00-winter/papers/phys_model.pdf

The orientation of the object will be kept in a matrix $R$, angular velocity in $\omega$, a vector.

The book says I can compute $\dot{R}$ by taking the skew-symmetric form of $\omega$ and multiply with each column of $R$. This is all fine, but how do I interface that with an numerical integrator, such as `scipy.odeint`? First of all this sofware expects flat vectors, do I flatten each $\tilde \omega \cdot R_i$ where $R_i$ is the $i$th column and $\tilde \omega$ is the skew-symmetric matrix of $\omega$?

Comment: The `.reshape` and `.flatten` methods are a useful pair for the transformation from flat array to more structured data and back. Slicing and `.concatenate` are also useful.

Comment: Can odeint work with piecemeal $\dot{R}$ components?

Comment: There is an `odeintw` package that provides a wrapper for some cases. `odeint` only works with flat arrays, how the components are interpreted has to be established inside the derivatives function.

Answer (score 0):

The code below seemed to work. As example used [this](https://github.com/burakbayramli/classnotes/blob/bb5778be908b8e48cd2c0abc96ce1e5b520f9fdc/phy/phy_008_sim_rigbod/torus.stl) Torus shape and
integrated a basic rotation equation,

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from stl import mesh

def skew(a):
   return np.array([[0,-a[2],a[1]],[a[2],0,-a[0]],[-a[1],a[0],0]])

your_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('torus.stl')
prop = your_mesh.get_mass_properties()
R0 = np.eye(3,3)
omega = np.array([0.0,1.0,0.0])
skew_omega = skew(omega)
   
def rhs(u,t):   
   R1x,R1y,R1z,R2x,R2y,R2z,R3x,R3y,R3z = u
   R = np.array([R1x,R1y,R1z,R2x,R2y,R2z,R3x,R3y,R3z])
   R = R.reshape((3,3)).T
   res = np.dot(skew_omega, R)
   return list(res.T.flatten())

STEPS = 20
t=np.linspace(0.0, 3.0, STEPS)
R0 = np.eye(3,3)
u0 = R0.flatten()
u1=odeint(rhs,list(u0),t)
```

Comment: Can you write down the differential equations involved?

Comment: $\frac{d R}{d t} = \tilde \omega \cdot R$. See the Pixar book link I shared for details.

Comment: I mean that you could add your details to your question/answer.

Comment: If you upvote I might

Comment: That's not how this site works. I am trying to improve the quality of the questions and answers here. That is, in part, my role as a moderator.